# PyQt5 QTableWidget | Detect Empty Cell - Disable Specific Columns and Rows

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have been looking for solutions to these two problems for over a week now. There are several similar questions regarding QTableWidget that I found on stack overflow as well as on other sites, however, there are not exactly what I am looking for or are geared towards Qt Designer which I am not using.

**Purpose of Application**:

This application calculates the datas entered into the Targeted column and the Receptions column and populates the remaining columns and the Totals row with the results of the sums, differences, and percentages of these calculations.

**Calculations**:

Totals = Wild card Round + Divisional Round + Championship + Super Bowl

Drops/Incomplete = Targeted - Receptions

Reception Percentage = (Receptions / Targeted) * 100

**Problems**:

Firstly, when you open the application all cells are empty. If the User clicks the Refresh button at this point, the application crashes. I implemented the check_null() and perform_calculations() functions to resolve this issue, however, the functions do not prevent the application from crashing until after the User enters datas into the Targeted column and the Receptions column (These two columns are the only ones the User needs to enter data into), and clicks Refresh. At this point, if the User deletes a data in either of these two columns, the two functions do their intended jobs. How do I prevent my application from crashing due to empty cells in the Targeted and Receptions columns?

Secondly, I do not want the User to be able to change the datas of the Drops/Incomplete column, the Receptions Percentage column, or the Totals row. These columns and row should not be editable. How do I make these two columns and one row uneditable?

**Code**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
from _ast import Is


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Stats Table Demo")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES/analytics.ico"))
        self.resize(1050, 350)
        self.gui()
        
    def gui(self):
        self.widgets()
        self.layouts()
        self.center_window()
        self.show()
        
    def widgets(self):
        self.header_lbl = QLabel("Playoffs Receiving Stats")
        self.header_lbl.setStyleSheet("font-family: Times; font-size: 26pt; font-weight: Bold;")
        self.header_lbl.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 10)
        
        self.refresh_lbl = QLabel("Refresh")
        self.refresh_lbl.setStyleSheet("font-family: Times; font-size: 14pt;")
        
        self.clear_lbl = QLabel("Clear")
        self.clear_lbl.setStyleSheet("font-family: Times; font-size: 14pt;")
        self.clear_lbl.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.refresh_image_btn = QToolButton()
        self.refresh_image_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES/refresh (1).png"))
        self.refresh_image_btn.setIconSize(QSize(15, 15))
        self.refresh_image_btn.setToolTip("Refresh Table")
        self.refresh_image_btn.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.refresh_image_btn.clicked.connect(self.perform_calculation)
        
        self.clear_image_btn = QToolButton()
        self.clear_image_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES/clear-all.png"))
        self.clear_image_btn.setIconSize(QSize(25, 25))
        self.clear_image_btn.setToolTip("Clear All")
        self.clear_image_btn.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.clear_image_btn.clicked.connect(self.clear_table)
        
        self.stats_tbl = QTableWidget()
        # Set the Height of the stats table
        self.stats_tbl.setMinimumHeight(255)
        self.stats_tbl.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        
        # Set every other row to grey color
        self.stats_tbl.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        
        self.stats_tbl.setRowCount(5)
        
        self.stats_tbl.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, QTableWidgetItem("Wild Card Round"))
        self.stats_tbl.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, QTableWidgetItem("Divisional Round"))
        self.stats_tbl.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, QTableWidgetItem("Championship"))
        self.stats_tbl.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, QTableWidgetItem("Super Bowl"))
        self.stats_tbl.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, QTableWidgetItem("Totals"))
        
        # set the Row Height for each row
        self.stats_tbl.setRowHeight(0, 45)
        self.stats_tbl.setRowHeight(1, 45)
        self.stats_tbl.setRowHeight(2, 45)
        self.stats_tbl.setRowHeight(3, 45)
        self.stats_tbl.setRowHeight(4, 45)
        
        self.stats_tbl.setColumnCount(4)
        
        # Prevents all Columns from being Edited
        # self.stats_tbl.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        
        self.stats_tbl.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QTableWidgetItem("Targeted"))
        self.stats_tbl.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QTableWidgetItem("Receptions"))
        self.stats_tbl.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, QTableWidgetItem("Drops/Incomplete"))
        self.stats_tbl.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, QTableWidgetItem("Reception Percentage"))
    
    def layouts(self):
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.header_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.controls_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.table_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.header_layout.addWidget(self.header_lbl)
        
        self.controls_layout.addWidget(self.refresh_lbl)
        self.controls_layout.addWidget(self.refresh_image_btn)
        self.controls_layout.addWidget(self.clear_lbl)
        self.controls_layout.addWidget(self.clear_image_btn)
        self.controls_layout.addStretch()
        
        self.table_layout.addWidget((self.stats_tbl))
        self.table_layout.addStretch()
        
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.header_layout)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.controls_layout)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.table_layout)
        
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        
    def perform_calculation(self):
        print(f"check_null(): {self.check_null()}")
        is_null = self.check_null()
        if is_null == 1:
            msg = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Null Cell", "Cells cannot be Null")
        else:
            self.calculate_datas()
    
    def calculate_datas(self):
        
        # =================== Totals ===================
        
        # =================== Targeted Column ===================
        
        # (0, 0)
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(0, 0).text())
        # (1, 0)
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(1, 0).text())
        # (2, 0)
        c = int(self.stats_tbl.item(2, 0).text())
        # (3, 0)
        d = int(self.stats_tbl.item(3, 0).text())
                
        total = a + b + c + d
        
        # (4, 0)
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(total)))
        
        # =================== Receptions Column ===================
        
        # (0, 1)
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(0, 1).text())
        # (1, 1)
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(1, 1).text())
        # (2, 1)
        c = int(self.stats_tbl.item(2, 1).text())
        # (3, 1)
        d = int(self.stats_tbl.item(3, 1).text())
                
        total = a + b + c + d
        
        # (5, 1)
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(total)))
        
        # =================== Drops Column ===================
        
        num_1 = int(self.stats_tbl.item(0, 0).text()) - int(self.stats_tbl.item(0, 1).text())
        num_2 = int(self.stats_tbl.item(1, 0).text()) - int(self.stats_tbl.item(1, 1).text())
        num_3 = int(self.stats_tbl.item(2, 0).text()) - int(self.stats_tbl.item(2, 1).text())
        num_4 = int(self.stats_tbl.item(3, 0).text()) - int(self.stats_tbl.item(3, 1).text())
        num_5 = int(self.stats_tbl.item(4, 0).text()) - int(self.stats_tbl.item(4, 1).text())
        
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(num_1)))
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(1, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(num_2)))
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(2, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(num_3)))
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(3, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(num_4)))
        self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(num_5)))
        
        # =================== Reception Percentages ===================
        
        # =================== Week 1 ===================
        
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(0, 0).text())
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(0, 1).text())
        
        if a == 0:
            msg_box = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Undefined", "The Total cannot equal 0.")
            
        else:
            percentage = (b / a) * 100
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(0, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str("{:.1f}%".format(percentage))))
            
    # =================== Week 2 ===================
        
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(1, 0).text())
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(1, 1).text())
        
        if a == 0:
            msg_box = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Undefined", "The Total cannot equal 0.")
            
        else:
            percentage = (b / a) * 100
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(1, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str("{:.1f}%".format(percentage))))
            
    # =================== Week 3 ===================
        
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(2, 0).text())
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(2, 1).text())
        
        if a == 0:
            msg_box = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Undefined", "The Total cannot equal 0.")
            
        else:
            percentage = (b / a) * 100
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(2, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str("{:.1f}%".format(percentage))))
            
    # =================== Week 4 ===================
        
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(3, 0).text())
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(3, 1).text())
        
        if a == 0:
            msg_box = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Undefined", "The Total cannot equal 0.")
            
        else:
            percentage = (b / a) * 100
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(3, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str("{:.1f}%".format(percentage))))
            
    # =================== Totals ===================
        
        a = int(self.stats_tbl.item(4, 0).text())
        b = int(self.stats_tbl.item(4, 1).text())
        
        if a == 0:
            # msg_box = QMessageBox.warning(self, "Undefined", "The Total cannot equal 0.")
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(a)))
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(a)))
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(a)))
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(a)))
            
        else:
            percentage = (b / a) * 100
            self.stats_tbl.setItem(4, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str("{:.1f}%".format(percentage))))
            
    def check_null(self):
        is_null = 0

        for row in range(0, 4):

            for column in range(0, 2):
                print(f"({row}, {column})")
                n = self.stats_tbl.item(row, column).text()
                if n == "":
                    is_null = 1
        
        return is_null
    
    def clear_table(self):
        self.stats_tbl.clearContents()
        
    def center_window(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
        
        
def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    App.setStyleSheet(
        
        '''
        
        QTableWidget {
            
            font-family: Times;
            font-size: 14pt;
            background-color: #CAE9fF;
            alternate-background-color: #5FA8D3;
            selection-background-color: #BEBEBE;
        }
        '''
    )
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Visual Example**:

[image]

Comment: Indexes that have no data set (they have not been edited yet or no `setItem()` has been called) are *null* items. First of all, check if `self.stats_tbl.item(row, column)` returns something different from `None`, then also remember to validate its input, otherwise your program will crash anyway since `int()` raises an exception if the string data is not numeral. Also: do not use `range(...)` with hardcoded values, **always** use the table widget [`rowCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#rowCount) and [`columnCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#columnCount) instead.

Comment: In my check_null() function I added the line `print("Check:", self.stats_tbl.item(0, 0))` in which it returned None. I also replaced the argument in the range() function with `range(self.stats_tbl.rowCount() - 1)` and `range(self.stats_tbl.columnCount() - 2)`. Lastly, I replaced `n = self.stats_tbl.item(row, column).text()` with `n = self.stats_tbl.item(row, column)`. As you suggested, these changes solved the issue. Now my application does not crash when the Refresh button is first clicked by the User. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the second issue regarding not allowing the two columns and one row being set to not-editable?

Comment: Why `range(self.stats_tbl.rowCount() - 2)`? That `- 2` is wrong, you have to cycle through *all* rows, so it should be `range(self.stats_tbl.rowCount())`. The hardcoded range might be `2` in your case, but just because you *know* that you only want to inspect the first two columns. The editing cannot be specifically disabled unless you explicitly set an item for those columns. You *must* add a QTableWidgetItem, and for that item you must `item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)`. Please carefully study the [model/view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) introduction.

Comment: Okay, this is frustrating and confusing. All of a sudden it does not work again. The message box is not appearing and the applications is crashing again. I don't understand why.

Comment: Then create a new question with a [mre] and we'll see, or eventually [edit] this one and add the new code, as long as it doesn't completely alter the original question.

Comment: I think I need to look at this issue more carefully before I ask anymore questions. Thank you very much for your help.